# Rails Ajax form submits twice

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery, asset-pipeline

I have a form that is rendered via ajax.  The form also submits with ajax.  When the form is submitted, it does a post request twice.

When someone clicks the "create profile" link, the form is rendered via ajax next to the link.  When the form is displayed, I need to include some javascript at the beginning of the view file in because the form requires these js files.  Here is the form:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/temp_js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/jquery_ujs.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/temp_js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/temp_js/jquery.c2selectbox.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/temp_js/jquery.colorbox-min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/temp_js/functions.js" %>

<%= form_for @profile, :html => { :class => "clearfix" }, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :description, :title => "Describe yourself and what you do." %>
    <%= f.file_field :pic, :class => "field file-field", :id => "file" %>
<%= f.submit "SAVE" %>
```

The files were already loaded on the page in the application.html.erb file, but they need to be loaded again when the form is displayed because elements in the form require the javascript.  The only problem is that the two top javascript files are for some reason causing the form to post twice.  I can''t get rid of them because the form needs them, but the form submits twice with them.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

I've seen some stack overflow pages saying I should delete the js files in my assets folder, but i need them for the form.  I've also read that Adding "config.serve_static_assets = false" to development.rb will fix the problem, but it does not.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

The problem definitely has to do with the jquery_ujs.js file.  If I remove that from the form code above, it does not execute twice.

Comment: you may try without sending a file? in your html is the multiform missing? as far as i know you need that to transmit files.

Comment: Thanks, tried that but it doesn't fix it.  Also, when I'm testing it and going through the form I haven't been submitting a picture.

Comment: to you have any other binding to a form submit? use the browser console.

Comment: I'm in the console inside firefox.  How do I check if something is binding to the form submit?

Comment: the easy way is first to disable other libs expect jquery and jquery_ujs

Comment: to you have the js in your layout or inside the code below? if you load jquery_ujs twice you may submit the form twice

Comment: The problem is definitely in either the query 1.8.3.min file or the query ujs file because if I get rid of all other javascript the problem is still there, but if i get rid of those two, the problem goes away. I have the js files in the layout and inside the code.  I need the js to load once with the application, but then I need it to load again after the form displays (unless you know another way).

Comment: remove the includes inside the code!

Comment: Inside the form code?  Then the form doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is having problems with this look at your layout file.  If it has more than one instance of the `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` tag
you will get the double submit action.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the asset pipeline, you're probably including `application.js`, which already includes all the scripts you need to do remote forms.

You're including a second copy with your explicit `<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/jquery_ujs.js" %>`, so all the event handlers are being bound twice.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a hacky way to do it, but i'm not sure if this is dangerous or not.  Essentially, i made a copy of the jquery_ujs file with the troubling section commented out.  The main page still calls the original jquery_ujs file but when the form is rendered with ajax the copy is called instead.  If you look at the query_ujs source code, i commented out everything under the line:

```
// Submits "remote" forms and links with ajax
```

Is this dangerous?  I'm a ruby on rails person so i second guess myself with things related to javascript and the asset pipeline.  I don't consider this to be the best answer so another answer will still probably be marked as correct.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i removed `//= require jquery_ujs` from application.js because I already had `//= require rails-ujs`.
This solved my problem.